# How to save a .GIF file into the gallery?

Tags: java, android, gallery, gif

Why is this so difficult to do in android? I know its easy for images, but why not .gifs?

I have this code here which saves it to an SD card, but I am trying to account for the user not having an SD card.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "GIFName_" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".gif");

try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    f.write(generateGIF(list));

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My app basically converts images to .GIFS, and right now it saves it on the sd card, but I want to save it to the gallery. Is there any way to do this easily? I know you can do it for images, but can you for .GIFS that are created?

Comment: Why not just save it to the sd card, then move it from the sd card to the gallery?

Comment: wait we can do that...?

Comment: I don't know, why not try it out?

Comment: its still the same problem though what if the user doesnt have an sd card...

Comment: Why not do it how you did the images, just specifying .gifs instead of .png or .jpg?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by `Gallery`? There is no directory called `Gallery`. However there is an application called `Gallery` and I hope that's what you mean.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return the root path to the external storage. This has no dependency to the file you are trying to save. If you want save to the `Pictures` directory, then you can do `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

`Gallery` is an application in android that scans the whole system and adds all media items to it. If you try saving a file, be it `.gif` or `.jpg`, or `.png`, programmatically in Android, there is no guarantee that the file will be picked up by `Gallery` immediately. That's why you need to use `MediaScannerConnection`. This will let you add your newly created file to be shown in Gallery.

Something like below:

`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);`

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)